# Jewish Calendar .ics Download

Tags: thunderbird, icalendar

I am using Lightning for Thunderbird and wanted to know if there is a location to download a calendar (in .ics format) which will plug in all the Jewish holidays.

Answer (score 2):

Shalom, Terence!
This is a web page that I found: http://www.hebcal.com/home/210/icalendar-ics-jewish-holidays